# " 'NoneType' object is not iterable" error when using fileinput python module to read lines from file

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm running the following python code in Linux environment that uses the fileinput library.

```
    filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(LOCAL_DESTINATION, "*.*"))
    for file in filelist:
        if comment_type.lower() == 'header':
            f = fileinput.input(file, inplace=1)
            print(f)
            print(f.__dict__)
            for xline in f:
                print(4567)
                if f.isfirstline():
                    sys.stdout.write(comments + '\n' + xline)
                else:
                    sys.stdout.write(xline)
```

```
The stderr I see even though the file is present in the LOCAL_DESTINATION folder:
'NoneType' object is not iterable
Exception ignored in: <bound method FileInput.__del__ of <fileinput.FileInput object at 0x7fb6164ed240>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/fileinput.py", line 229, in __del__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/fileinput.py", line 233, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/fileinput.py", line 290, in nextfile
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable``


Can someone tell what could be the problem.
```

P.S. f.**dict** prints out the following:
{'_file': None, '_backup': '', '_openhook': None, '_filename': None, '_savestdout': None, '_mode': 'r', '_inplace': 1, '_startlineno': 0, '_files': ('4f5b11ef-601f-4607-a4d0-45173d2bbc53/Q3_2019_PlacementGUID_555168561629745350_f99a8d275e4_11_13_2019.txt',), '_isstdin': False, '_filelineno': 0, '_backupfilename': None, '_output': None}```

Comment: provide complete error message

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Here there are two places where you are iterating over collection.

```py
for file in filelist:
```

```py
for xline in f:
```

The error means, either `filelist` or `f` return `None` instead of any elements. In other words, there is nothing to iterate on, it's not even an empty collection - it doesn't have a value.

You could use something list below to avoid error. However, you must check and handle empty collection.

```py
for file in filelist or []:
```

```py
for xline in f or []:
```

Comment: I fixed the "empty collection" part, maybe I overstepped, you tell me if that's okay.

Comment: I'm getting <fileinput.FileInput object at 0x7f62e53cb7f0> when I print f

Comment: @Kuldeep, That print out means, you are printing the memory address.You can read more here https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html

Comment: @CorentinPane, that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You get error

> 'NoneType' object is not iterable

when you try to loop over `None` or null value

eg.

```
k = None
for i in k:
    print(k)
```

In above case you will get an error as you are trying to iterate over `None` value.

In your case you have 2 for loops

`for file in filelist` and `for xline in f`

so either `filelist` is None or `f` is None

Comment: I'm getting <fileinput.FileInput object at 0x7f62e53cb7f0> when I print f

Comment: For one of the iteration you must be getting `None`

Comment: Okay I'll check and let you know Thanks for answering :)